# Pillow is not installing in Django when I creating a new Project

Tags: django, cl.exe

[ error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
]

When I created my first project Pip install pillow installed successfully but when I created a new project then pip install pillow was showing this error. I don't know what is happening with this.

Comment: did you make virtual enviorment for every project?

Comment: Try creating a different python environment and installing? Sometimes thing like spelling mistakes causes such an issue.

Comment: yes I did it. Still not working.

Comment: It's still not working showing same error. I don't know what is happening with this.